# How to use favicon

Tags: java, html, spring

In my previous app without spring I just needed to use

```
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../resources/images/favicon.png" />
```

and the favicon worked. Now I'm using spring mvc and I don't get any error but it also doesn't load the image to the browser's title.

What's the difference in spring?

Comment: and before u ask, yes the path is right.

Comment: without the folder structure and the resource configuration we can't say anything

Comment: **it's not the path**. If I search it on my browser it is there. http://localhost:8080/../resources/img/favicon.png